# routing not working - Webapi ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a mvc application with an index page(static html) under the Home view. I could view the page. The routeconfig is :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I am adding a WebAPI controller and am trying to invoke the Get.

```
public class TopicsController : ApiController
    {
         public string Get()
        {
            return "Hello WebAPI";
        }

    }
```

The route config in Webapi is :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Added the application start function :

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();


            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

When i try the following:

> http://localhost:11001/api/Topics

I am getting the following error:

**Not found :(
Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist.**

Comment: Please can you show us how your config.Routes.MapHttpRoute() is being called?  Is it being called from your application's Global.asax file?

Comment: @Luke i have added the application start function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change registration order in Global.asax

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the default project from visual studio, you will notice that the order you add the routes is very important, because 'api/topics' algo matches the mvc route, that is why it tells you that it doesn't exist, because you don't have a 'api' controller.

Change it to this:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

leave the rest like you have it

EDIT:

Updated the answer to reflect the WebAPI version from the question.

But in the last version of WebAPI:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

should be:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Comment: GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); is throwing an error stating "Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration' cannot be used like a method.". Also i could not find the GlobalConfiguration.Configure method, instead only configuration was available.

Comment: Most probably is a matter of mvc versions: use WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

Comment: `Take a look at the default project from Visual Studio` thanks